# Average of datetime data type

Tags: sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I am trying to calculate the average of a few rows with a `datetime` data type (standard datetime format).
How can I do that?

Comment: Convert them to seconds, calculate AVG and convert result seconds back

Comment: For a question like that you should really specify the RDBMS. They all have special features when it comes to timestamps.

Answer (score 9):

Convert the datetime to a `float`.  The SQL standard defines that as the number of days since 1900, so it should be fairly portable.  For example:

```
declare @t table (dt datetime)
insert @t select '1950-01-01'
union all select '1960-01-01'

select cast(avg(cast(dt as float)) as datetime) from @t
```

This result is`1955-01-01`.  [Example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114598/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how to get the average of a DateTime column in MySql:

```
create temporary table table_1 (
    aDate DateTime
);

insert into table_1 values
    ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2010-01-01 00:00:00');

select CAST(avg(aDate) as DateTime) from table_1;
-- Result: "2005-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

In **PostgreSQL** you could:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(avg(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM my_timestamp)))
  FROM my_tbl;
```

More info in the fine manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html).